# GPS 4-layer stackup

Tags: gps

I'm developing a GPS module with passive ceramic patch antenna, I need suggestions if the following 4-layer stackup I've chosen might work:

- Top layer has the ceramic patch antenna and a status LED,
- Inner1 might be power plane/signal,
- Inner2 GND reference plane,
- Bottom layer where I've placed many components it's Sig/PWR